# Are imported Excel pivot tables dynamic?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerbi

I'm making a dashboard with PowerBI. My question is if I import the Pivot table as Excell, does the data still update? Or do I need to find another solution?

Comment: Can't test with the database i'm working, don't have the permissions for it. I cant only read the data

Answer (score 0):

Forgot that I asked this question, but no. When you update your Excel PowerBI will update, but you need to update your Excel manually

Comment: I think it is possible to have updates between PowerBI and Excel if you have set the report up correctly via the [Cloud](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-data) solution. I don't know if this is bi-directional. The source, however, has to be up to date.